# Identify unique CollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I want each CollectionViewCell to show an image and hide a label if it is tapped. But if the user scrolls the image suddenly is displayed in other cess that haven't been touched. How can I identify certain cells?

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    println("user tapped on door number \(indexPath.row)")

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    if (cell.myLabel.text == "1") {
        one = true

            if (cell.myLabel.hidden) {
                cell.myLabel.hidden = false
                cell.MyImageView.image = nil

            }
            else {
                cell.myLabel.hidden = true
                cell.MyImageView.image = UIImage(named:"1")!
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because cells are reused so instead of changes each cell, change the data source at the index of the cell that was tapped.

Comment: Could you give an example?